# Is the null space of a non invertible matrix the same as the eigenspace for the eigenvalue of 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have a matrix A, such that A is non invertible, then

$\implies$ the equation Av = 0 has non trivial solutions

In order for a constant to be an eigenvalue for a matrix Ax = $\lambda$x must be satisfied such that x $\not=$ 0

Since all vectors which are non trivial solutions also known as nul A, follow the requirement of x $\not=$ 0 and when multiplied by A are equal to 0, $\implies$ the vectors of the null space of A, undergoing a transformation of A, will map to 0 $\implies$ the eigenvalue 0 will describe the position of the vectors under the transformation of A

I know this is very basic reasoning but would this constitute as a proof, and is this proof even correct?

Comment: Yes, by definition.

Comment: @MatyMangoo Okay thank you!

Comment: Just a note, all this will make sense only when $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: @AnuragA, Right thank you